# Use one entity from two context instance entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I create instance of context per form and may multi forms use same entity
How handle this when save?

Comment: Define "handle this" and read [ask] and show what you have tried. You mean you have two forms open on the same entity, and the last one to save wins? Go read about concurrency and decide what you want to do if another form edited an entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-6.0, even though that's about MVC, the same principles apply.

Comment: Why not use instance of context per app?

Comment: One instace per app may load hug entity tracker

Comment: @Sergey because it's WinForms, which may run for hours if not days? That's not a good lifetime for a DbContext.

Comment: @codecaster if i use same entity from two instance context ,when change state return error

Comment: "when change state of return error" - what?

Comment: entity cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Comment: So you're passing the entity from one form to the other? Don't do that, pass the ID(s).

Comment: *I create instance of context per form* - this sounds like a bad idea. Forms are very long lived things. Contexts are supposed to be very short lived things. Strive for a pattern of "new context, download entity, modify entity, save entity, destroy context" in a few seconds.. It'll serve you better. If you're going to keep these things longer, brush up on the options for managing concurrency..

Comment: Also in smart client application it may be the best approach to follow [disconnected entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities). The only problem is keeping the same entities in sync among forms. You need to give a lot more details to get any more pointed help here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DbContext is part of your "view state", intended to give you access to the database, hold a copy of the data the user is working on in the Change Tracker, and flush changes back to the database.

In a smart client app the natural scope and lifetime for the DbContext is either global or scoped to a UI element that represents a task or use-case.  But in either case you have to prevent the DbContext's Change Tracker from growing too large or from holding on to copies of data too long, as even a single form can stay open all day.  A possible rule-of-thumb for these apps is to clear the change tracker after every successful SaveChanges().  Other than that, of course you must avoid long-running transactions so the DbContext doesn't hold a DbConnection open for a long time, but you have to do that anyway.  The point is that a DbContext with an empty change tracker can be long-lived.

Using a Short-Lived DbContext is possible, but you loose the services of the Change Tracker and .Local ObservableCollection which make data binding really easy.  So that's not a silver bullet.

So on to the question at-hand, if you have DbContext-per-form, and you have form-to-form communication of entities which end up getting saved by a different DbContext, you really have no choice but to disconnect the entities from their home DbContext before sending them over.

Or this might indicate that the two forms really should share a View State, and you should create an explicit View State object that includes the DbContext and the entieies and have both share that between forms.

Take a look at the [Model-View-ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) (MVVM) pattern which introduces a distinction between the View (form) and the ViewModel, the  data that models the use case user's interaction with the app.  It's a useful pattern and is very widely used in XAML-based smart clients.  Also XAML is (still) the [future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui) of smart client apps, so it's useful to learn.